# What is the difference between docker host and node?

Tags: docker, deployment, containers, docker-swarm

I know that questions similar to this one is already asked on SO. But, it doesn't make clarification on what I am looking for.

I am trying to get my hands dirty on docker. I have encountered the terminology `docker host` and `docker node`. I am referring this article:- https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#docker-composeyml.

I know that docker host is the one, which runs one or more containers and in which docker engine is installed. Moreover, docker host can either be a physical machine or it can be a virtual machine.

But I am confused about docker node. How it's different from docker host ? When a docker host becomes docker node ?

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A docker host refers to the server in the client server pair. It's the instance of the dockerd engine, and where containers are run.

A docker node refers to a member in a swarm mode cluster. Every swarm node must be a docker host, but not every docker host is necessarily a member of a swarm cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The terms are used interchangeably and there is no difference.